# Can two headers contain indentically named classes in C++?

Tags: c++, class, header, include

And both be included by a project, if they are in different namespaces? I'm having a problem just including them because of duplicity...

Comment: There should be no problem including them if they are in different namespaces, can you paste some code?

Comment: If you're having trouble including them, don't add the directories containing them to you include path, but instead the parents of those directories. That way you specify the containing directory in your #include statement and it will distinguish them.

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no.

The name of the class `Foo` in `namespace1` is "namespace1::Foo"

The name of the class `Foo` in `namespace2` is "namespace2::Foo"

These names are not identical - you cannot have two identically named classes in different namespaces.

Obviously, both have a local name of "Foo" and if you do something like

```
using namespace namespace1;
using namespace namespace2;

Foo x;
```

then there will be an ambiguity, as you've told the compiler to ignore the different bit of the names.

But as long as you don't bring both into scope, you can use the full name to use either of them as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if they are in different namespaces, they don't really have the same name.

Show us your headers & your CPP file, but please abbreviate them!

Answer (score 0):

Yes if they are in different namespaces  of you don't use both of them in a third location.. are you sure the problem is related to the names and not something like cyclic references?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the two classes are in different namespaces, you can include them in the same file without problems.  C++ only complains if it finds two definitions for classes with the same fully-qualified name, and fully-qualified names include the namespace.

Your problem is likely elsewhere... as mentioned above, posting code will make it easier for people to diagnose the problem.